# set spark vm options

Tags: maven, apache-spark

I'm trying to build a spark application which uses zookeeper and kafka. Maven is being used for build. The project I'm trying to build is [here](https://github.com/baghelamit/video-stream-analytics/tree/master/video-stream-processor). On executing:

```
mvn clean package exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.iot.video.app.spark.processor.VideoStreamProcessor"
```

It shows

```
ERROR SparkContext:91 - Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: System memory 253427712 must be at least 471859200. Please increase heap size using the --driver-memory option or spark.driver.memory in Spark configuration.
```

I tried adding `spark.driver.memory 4g` to spark-defaults.conf but I still get the error. How can I fix it?

Comment: try `export` in the command line to see if there are any environmental variables that could be overriding this. if not, are you sure that spark is reading your `spark-defaults.conf`?

Answer (score 0):

You can send extra JVM options to your workers by using dedicated spark-submit arguments:

```
spark-submit --conf 'spark.executor.memory=1g'\
      --conf 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Xms1024m -Xmx4096m'
```

Similarly, you can set the option for your driver (useful if your application is submitted in cluster mode, or launched by spark-submit):

```
--conf 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Xms512m -Xmx2048m'
```